# Como saber se o Oracleparameter é null. DataAccessClient

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Olá, estou mudando de provider, saindo de OracleClient para OracleDataAccess.Client e estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

Como trabalho com Procedures eu utilizo um GetParameter que me retorna um decimal.

```
 public decimal GetParameterValue(string pParameterName)
    {
        try
        {
            return (decimal)(OracleDecimal)_command.Parameters[pParameterName].Value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return default(decimal);
        }
      
    }
```

Coloquei dentro de um try pois não consegui verificar se o resultado é null. Sei que inteiros, decimal não permitem nulos, porem não encontrei uma outra forma de resolver.

Em OracleClient estava assim:

```
if (_command.Parameters[pParameterName].Value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            lResult = default(decimal);
        }
```

Porem quando mudei de provider isso parou de funcionar.

Alguem sabe como fazer, pois da forma que esta hoje fica muito ruim.  E por ser parametros do sistema existem muitos casos onde o valor é null.

Answer (score -2):

Testei uma solução e deu certo. No lugar do convencional DbNull passei direto o null. Não muito elegante porem funcional.

```
public decimal GetParameterValue(string pParameterName)
    {

        try
        {
            if(_command.Parameters[pParameterName].Value == null)
                return default(decimal);
            else
                 return (decimal)(OracleDecimal)_command.Parameters[pParameterName].Value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(decimal);
        }
       
    }
```

Caso alguem queira saber a diferença entre DbNull e null segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)